# Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated - PHP7

Tags: php, macos, apache, php-7

I have viewed all previous posts regarding this error and am still having issues.

This error only appears when using Chrome (my version is 51).

I had PHP5.6 installed when I first received this error, so I edited php.ini to uncomment and set:

```
always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
```

However, the error still appeared. (Yes, restarted apache, etc.)

So, I upgraded to PHP7 - and there is no *always_populate_raw_post_data* value - yet I am still getting this error. I even added in always_populate_raw_post_data = -1 at the end of the new php.ini anyway.

Here is the full error log:

```
Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'Bearer <br />

<b>Deprecated</b>:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is
deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this
warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use
the php://input stream instead. in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b>
```

This error is preventing all my pages from working.

*I should also note* that when I was running PHP5.6 and updated the always_populate_raw_post_data value, my phpinfo.php file showed that it was set to -1. But the error still appeared and code not properly executed.

Comment: Are you sure you changed the right php.ini? You can check the loaded php.ini with `phpinfo()`

Comment: Are you sure you're using `php://input`?  Do note that the warning is very justified and is telling you that your code is bad (awful actually) and should get corrected.

Comment: @JuliePelletier lmao thanks. the code giving the error is from a github package that is not my own. many instances where i could change to php://input, so i guess i will get looking.

Comment: @Perry yes I changed the same php.ini as noted in my phpinfo(). The value does not appear now that I am using PHP7 - but when I had PHP56 it did show the value set to -1 in phpinfo()

Comment: lol solved it. it kept showing the old error from 5.6 until i cleared my cache :$ (depite clearing php artisan cache, closing and restarting, etc)... just as i thought though, no changes to `php://input` required, @JuliePelletier ;).